# How to pass array value in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to pass php value in javascript. I run a query and apply if statement and while array on javascript. But always show empty result. I can't find the problem. anyone please help me. Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
$SUserName=$_SESSION['view'];
include 'dbconnect.php';

$query="select * from user_permission where username='$SUserName'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

?>



        <script type="text/javascript">

        d = new dTree('d');
        d.add(0,-1,'Dhuronto');
        <?php
                if($SUserName=='sumon@dhuronto.com')
                    {
                    echo "d.add(1,0,'Admin','blank.php', 'Admin', 'main');";

                    }
                    else {
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                     echo "d.add('$id','$pid','$node','$url', '$node', 'main');";
                            }
                    }

                ?>

</script>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @PleaseStand.. I see everyone copying and pasting this warning. does anyone realize that the links in it **DO NOT** work?

Comment: @PleaseStand Are you copy pasting this comment in every question which has `mysql_*` functions !!?

Comment: @ROYFinley Every single link in this comment works for me.

Comment: @Tomalak That's not the problem. the problem is he is pasting it in every single posts that have `mysql_*` functions !

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML code?

Comment: Please stop posting about mysql_* functions on questions. Until the mysql extension is removed from every server in the world it's not really an issue that you need to post on every SO question that has mysql_ in it. Ask yourself: "**Does it help the user find an answer to the question?**"

Comment: @Siamak.A.M That's not what Roy Finley complained about. Besides, what's wrong with the comment? `mysql_*` *is* deprecated and needs to be put into disuse, better sooner than later. So what's your point?

Comment: @Siamak How is this a problem? It's important to warn users who might not otherwise be aware of the problems plaguing the `mysql_*` functions. Considering how many tutorials still display the outdated and deprecated functions, it's hardly a bad thing to do a good job warning people about it.

Comment: @popnoodles Some languages that still support GOTO statements. *"But it's in the language, so it's not a problem to use it."* is a very shaky argument.

Comment: The two aren't comparable.

Comment: @popnoodles Yes, they are. Both are in the "There's nothing wrong with it if it's used right, it's just so goddamn hard to use right" category. In general, there's nothing wrong with people pointing out best practices, too few are doing it, even. That you are annoyed with a particular comment does not invalidate its point.

Comment: Pointing out best practices perfectly normal, posting that on every question that includes mysql_ is obsessive.

Answer (score 0):

Where are '$id','$pid','$node','$url', '$node' coming from?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "d.add('$id','$pid','$node','$url', '$node', 'main');";
}
```

Did you mean

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "d.add('$row[id]','$row[pid]','$row[node]','$row[url]', '$row[node]', 'main');";
}
```

NB - i wouldn't use the above syntax myself, it being the only time you can write vars as `$row[id]`.  I prefer

```
echo "d.add('" . $row['id']. "','" . $row['pid']. "'...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the names of the columns as if they are variables. You need to get them from the array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "d.add('{$row['id']}','{$row['pid']}','{$row['node']}','{$row['url']}', '{$row['node']}', 'main');";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you have not defined values for `$id`, `$pid`, and so on. That said, you can use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to JavaScript encode PHP data types properly, assuming your text is UTF-8 encoded:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // I don't know your database schema, so this could be wrong
    $args = array(
        $row['id'], 0, htmlspecialchars($row['username']),
        'blank.php', '', 'main'
    );

    // echo 'd.add.apply(d,' . json_encode($args) . ');';
    echo 'd.add(' . implode(',', array_map('json_encode', $args)) . ');';
}
```

Note that dTree is sort of an outdated JavaScript library that has fallen behind current best practices. It was [last updated](http://destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/) in 2003! You might want to look into newer, better alternatives such as those mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710114/jquery-tree-plugin.

Comment: Considering there are two instances of `node` in the argument list I doubt that will work.